# How to merge back k-means clustering outputs to the corresponding units in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, k-means

I just wonder this strategy is the correct way to merge back the k-means clustering outputs to the corresponding units in the existing dataframe.

For example, I have a data set which includes user ID, age, income, gender and I want to run a k-means clustering algorithm to find a set of clusters where each cluster has similar users in terms of these characteristics (age, income, gender). 
 Note that I disregard the value difference among the characteristics for the brevity.

```
existing_dataframe

user_id age income gender
1       13  10     1 (female)
2       34  50     1
3       75  40     0 (male)
4       23  29     0
5       80  45     1
...     ... ...    ...

existing_dataframe_for_analysis 
(Based on my understanding after referring number of tutorials from online sources, 
I should not include user_id variable, so I use the below dataframe for the analysis;
please let me know if I am wrong) 

age income gender
13  10     1 (female)
34  50     1
75  40     0 (male)
23  29     0
80  45     1
...     ... ...    ...
```

Assume that I found the optimal number of clusters from the dataset is 3. So I decided to set it as 3 and predict in which cluster each user is categorized using the below code.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans(n_clusters=3, 
               init='k-means++',
               max_iter=20,
               n_init=10) 
model.fit(existing_dataframe_for_analysis)

predicted=model.predict(existing_dataframe_for_analysis)

print (predicted[:5])
```

The expected out can be shown below:

```
[0 1 2 1 2]
```

If I run the below code where I create a new column called 'cluster' which represents the analysis outputs and add the colum to the existing dataframe, does it gaurantee that *nth* element from the output list corresponds to the *nth* observation (user id) in the existing dataframe? Please advice.

```
existing_dataframe['cluster']=predicted
print (existing_dataframe)

output:
user_id age income gender      cluster
1       13  10     1 (female)  0
2       34  50     1           1
3       75  40     0 (male)    2
4       23  29     0           1
5       80  45     1           2
...     ... ...    ...         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to rejoin the predictions is correct. Your assumption to not include any ids is also correct. However, I strongly advise you to scale your input variables before doing any clustering, as your variables have different units.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
scaler = StandardScaler() 
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(existing_dataframe_for_analysis)
```

Then continue working with this new object as you did before.